# After Windows update, normal to get prompt for Administrator password?

Tags: windows-10, updates

In my decades of using Windows, I've never gotten prompted for an administrator password when logging into a non-administrator account after a Windows update.  Today, on Windows 10, I did, and the reason was to run two apps.  One was "Setup", whose verified publisher was Acer (the OEM for my laptop) and another was for BitDefender, which subsequently showed a notification in the notification centre that it needed to be activated.  Each of of these resulted in a prompt for the administrator password.

I'm wondering whether this is normal.  In my experience, it is unprecedented, but I'm just one person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite possible that the Windows update reconfigured or reset something which prompted a reinstallation of the said programs. I've personally never seen anything like that but it doesn't strike me as something beyond the realm of possibility.

Comment: No, it isn't beyond possible.  It seems like we're of the same mind.  Possible,  but never saw this before.  Which leaves me wondering.....I appreciate your sharing.